# Can't bind to 'options' since it isn't a known property of 'p-dropdown'

Tags: angular, primeng

Getting this error when trying to add a primeNG dropdown to userform.component.ts, I've referenced this but to no avail as I already have this fix immplemented: [primeng dropdown component error ('p-dropdown' is not a known element)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44325070/primeng-dropdown-component-error-p-dropdown-is-not-a-known-element)

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'options' since it isn't a known property of 'p-dropdown'.
1. If 'p-dropdown' is an Angular component and it has 'options' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-dropdown' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("<p-dropdown [ERROR ->][options] = "technologies" [autoWidth] = "false" id = "technologies"></p-dropdown>
```

GIT REPO: https://github.com/BillyCharter87/Tech-O-Dex

Thanks!

Comment: You didn't import the UserformModule inside of the AppModule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may possible that you are using `p-dropdown` in another component and in that another component's module you have not imported `DropdownModule`. I did the same mistake and got resolved by putting `DropdownModule` in `AppModule` as well as in specific component's Module.

Answer (score 9):

Normally, this error occurs when you missed some imports.
Please add these line if missing:

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { DropdownModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
```

And add them in imports as well.

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure you have this setup:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [YourComponent],
  imports: [DropdownModule],
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have added refrence library in yourcomponent.module.ts
like below:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } 
    from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
  
import { CalendarModule } from 'primeng/calendar';

import {ListboxModule} from 'primeng/listbox';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ListboxModule,
    FormsModule,
    CalendarModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score -2):

The Angular's error message is pretty verbose and if you read it carefully, you can easily solve the problem on your own.

The first item applies to your case: you know that `p-dropdown` is an Angular component and you know that it has `options` input. The error message asks you to verify that it is a part of the module you're using it in. And indeed, you're [trying to use](https://github.com/BillyCharter87/Tech-O-Dex/blob/bc70303ff4c8b025ca9bbf69868aabd132e3703f/src/app/userform/userform.component.html) a component [without importng the module wich exports it](https://github.com/BillyCharter87/Tech-O-Dex/blob/bc70303ff4c8b025ca9bbf69868aabd132e3703f/src/app/userform/userform.module.ts#L8-L12).